# Node JS: Automatic selection of `http.get` vs `https.get`

Tags: node.js, get

I have a Node JS app that needs to download a file, given a URL at run-time.

The URL may be either `http://` or `https://`.

How do I best cater for the different protocols?

At the moment I have:

```
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');

var protocol = (parsedUrl.protocol == 'https:' ? https : http);
protocol.get(parsedUrl, function(res) {
  ...
});
```

... but it feels clunky.

Thanks!

Comment: Some clarification: Is it your server side Node app that needs to download a file from another server, or an application that needs to download something from your Node app?

Comment: Server-side Node app that's downloading from another server. Thanks!

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I had a similar need, but didn't need the full blown request or needle libraries, I have the following code (which is slightly different)

```
var adapterFor = (function() {
  var url = require('url'),
    adapters = {
      'http:': require('http'),
      'https:': require('https'),
    };

  return function(inputUrl) {
    return adapters[url.parse(inputUrl).protocol]
  }
}());
//.. and when I need it
adapterFor(url).get(url, ...)
```

Comment: this shoudl be the accepted answer! Except would it possibly be better to store the adapters object outside of the function so that way it doesn't re-require http and http each time a request is made? or is the nodejs require function executed only once regardless of how many times it is called?

Comment: @bluejayke require can be called any number of times but a module is evaluated once and cached, this one of defining features of JS modules. This isn't relevant to the code above as there's not just a function but IIFE (for no good reason) so `require` are called once.

Answer (score 16):

There's a bunch of modules you could use instead, like [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) or [needle](https://github.com/tomas/needle). They'll figure out which protocol to use, and how to handle redirects (if required) and such.

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping Node might have something built-in, but not to worry. I appreciate you pointing me towards Request and Needle - they look great.